# Hide logs from iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, console.log

I'm working on a Reactjs app where I'm sometimes showing external content using an iframe tag. It works fine but some of those sites are poorly designed and I get a lot of unwanted things in my console log. The reasons why I don't want these are firstly because they flood my console log hiding other information I really should pay attention to and secondly because I think they impact the performance.

I've tried to override the console.log but that didn't work, and if it, did it's still not really what I want since that would remove my own logs that I still want to see.

Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/filter-console

Comment: No, but you can filter the console. What makes you think they impact performance? The performance of what?

Comment: Regarding the performance; this is purely based on the speculation that printing a lot in the log should consume more than not printing at all. I have done no measurements here.